# Parse command line arguments in Lex

Tags: c, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

Suppose I want my Lex and Yacc program to parse the command line arguments like:

```
./a.out show memory
```

I want lex to parse the string "show memory". How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to concatenate all the arguments into a big string, by inserting whitespace between them. Then feed the remaining text buffer to Lex/Yacc, by re-defining the `YY_INPUT` macro so it reads input from your text buffer.

The start could be something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *argbuf;
size_t arglen;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;

  // Compute total length of all arguments, with a single space between.
  arglen = 0;
  for(i = 1; argv[i] != NULL; i++)
    arglen += 1 + strlen(argv[i]);

  // Allocate buffer space.
  argbuf = malloc(arglen);
  if(argbuf == NULL)
  {
     fprintf(stderr, "No memory for argument buffer, aborting");
     exit(1);
  }

  // Concatenate all arguments. This is inefficient, but simple.
  argbuf[0] = 0;
  for(i = 1; argv[i] != NULL; i++)
  {
    if(i > 1)
      strcat(argbuf, " ");
    strcat(argbuf, argv);
  }

  // Here we should be ready to call yyparse(), if we had implemented YY_INPUT().

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: could u please tell me how to modify YY_INPUT in the above case i mentioned.

Comment: i am getting these errors when i try the above code


try.y:8: error: syntax error before '{' token
try.y:10: error: `c' undeclared here (not in a function)
try.y:10: error: `EOF' undeclared here (not in a function)
try.y:10: error: `YY_NULL' undeclared here (not in a function)
try.y:10: error: `buf' undeclared here (not in a function)
try.y:10: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
try.y:11: error: syntax error before '}' token

Comment: @ajai: It's easier to help you if you simply edit your question with any additional information.

Comment: @unwind: ok as i said i want to parse the arguements which i give to executable file. for eg: ajai show memory. where ajai is the executable file and show memory are the arguements. 


when i redefined yy_input as given in the example still it is not reading the arguements so pls tell me how to go about it

Comment: @ajai: I meant you shouldn't post new comments, you should edit the original question, above. But perhaps you can't (due to reputation requirements), I'm not sure how it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc > 1) {
    if(argv[1])
        yy_scan_string(argv[1]);
    }
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with doing it the old fashioned way?:

```
if(argc > 1 && !strcmp(argv[1],"show"))
{
    if(argc > 2)
    {
        if(!strcmp(argv[2],"memory"))
            ...
        else if(!strcmp(argv[2],"cpu"))
            ...
        else ...
    }
}
```

Besides, `getopt()` and friends are more appropriate.

Comment: no i can't use dis method bcoz i have 20 keywords . moreover there is no order in which dey should occur

Comment: OK, go with unwind's method then, but I smell over engineering.

Answer (score 0):

My blog article [Parsing command line parameters with Yacc & Flex](http://www.myrkraverk.com/blog/2017/10/parsing-command-line-parameters-with-yacc-flex/) explains this with a working example.  There is no need to concatenate the argument string.  The reason is given in the article.

The blurb is:

> Every once in a while someone comes along and asks how to parse
> command line parameters with Yacc & Flex. This is rather straight
> forward, but requires some knowledge of the generated code to get
> right.
>
> Here we present a source template that does this. The user only has to
> edit the grammar and scanning rules. Some knowledge of C, Yacc and
> Flex is assumed.
>
> The code is WTFPL licensed
>
> The template is written for Berkeley Yacc and the reflex variant of
> Flex. It may be made to work with GNU Bison and SourceForge Flex,
> possibly with a few changes.

What you get is a template where you can just insert your lexical and grammar specification.

Please ask questions about the using and adapting the template itself to the blog comments.

Comment: Link to the blog is down ! Opera does not host blog  anymore !

Comment: Oh, right.  And sorry about the very, very late reply.

Comment: I'll put the code on my new blog and fix the link one of these days.

Comment: And the blog post is finally re-published and the link's fixed.